# javascript link opens the second time I click it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript link I want to open, but it is only working the second I click on it. I want to click a Div I have created for this, and there are no anchor tags involved.

The HTML I use:

```
<li>
    <div class="artikel_box_lk">
        <div class="button" rel="$productNameSeo">
            <span>More Info >></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The javascript code I use for this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".artikel_box_lk").click(function(e) {

        if($(e.target).hasClass("button")) window.open("/lk/" + $(e.target).attr("rel"), "_blank");
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, the strange thing happening is that if I click on it a couple of times it sometimes works. I must have forgotten something crucial here, but cannot seem to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `.button` to your click selector:

```
$(function(){
    $( ".artikel_box_lk .button" ).click(function( e ) {
        window.open( "/lk/" + $( this ).attr("rel"), "_blank");
    });
});
```

I suppose first time you click outside `.button` div

Comment: This works correctly! Thanks for showing me the way.. Will accept in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you say if the `e.target` has class name of "button"; that would only be true when you click in areas where the span element and its' parent don't overlap. When you click on the span element, it would say the "target" is the "span" element and it does not have the class name "button". Always do a `console.log($(e.target));` to debug the issue.